# Boost thread fails BOOST_ASSERT( px != 0 );

Tags: c++, assert, boost-thread

I have created a future object, as such:

Future.h

```
#ifndef FUTURE_H_
#define FUTURE_H_

#include "../interfaces/IFuture.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost;

class Future: public IFuture {
private:
    void** data;
    bool isDataReady;
    mutex mut;
    condition_variable cond;

public:
    Future();

    ~Future();

    bool isReady();

    void setData(void* data[]);

    void** getData();
};

#endif /* FUTURE_H_ */
```

Future.cpp

```
#include "../headers/Future.h"

Future::Future(){
    this->data = NULL;
    this->isDataReady = false;
}

Future::~Future(){
    delete [] data;
}

bool Future::isReady(){
    return isDataReady;
}

void Future::setData(void* data[]){
    if(isDataReady)
        return;
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mut);
        this->data = data;
        isDataReady = true;
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}

void** Future::getData(){
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mut);
    while(!isDataReady){
        cond.wait(lock);
    }
    return data;
}
```

The main application creates multiple Future objects as needed.
The first object work fine, but around the one-hundredth Future object the condition.wait(mut) fails the BOOST_ASSERT( px != 0 ); in intrusive_ptr.hpp.

I do not understand why this is happening.

I am using boost thread in windows on the mingw g++ compiler.

Comment: Boost already provides future objects. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures

Comment: I am aware of that. By I dont want to be tied to a specific implementation. If further down the line I wish to use pthreads instead, I only have to change my Future object. Anyway, is something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Can you should a minimal example code how you use the Future?

Comment: in function main:  

for(...){
   IFuture* f = execute(...);
   void** data = futures[k]->getData();
    ...
}

The execute function creates a future and returns. A callback function later gives the data to the Future object.

Comment: How is the data that's being passed to `setData()` allocated?  Since you're storing it as a `void**` the `delete[]` operation might not be doing the right thing if it's not actually allocated using `new void* [some_number]`.

Comment: It is allocated elsewhere by malloc, in both dimentions. The aplication that gets the data from the future does not need the array just every position. That's why I delete the outter array.

Comment: @User: I'm not sure what you mean by "both dimensions" or "does not need the array just every position", but if the memory pointed to by `data` was allocated by `malloc()` then freeing it using `delete[]` is wrong and may corrupt the heap.

Comment: What I mean by both dimensions is that the outter application does not need the void** just the pointers stored in that array, in seperate. Ok, it seams that I should only use delete[] if i called new...I thought free and delete were equivalent

Comment: I corrected the delete [] calls but the original error is still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem "fixed". Started using Visual Studio and its compiler. Boost thread and MinGW are not very compatible.

Answer (score 2):

In `Future::setData` you're unlocking a mutex you don't hold (becuase it's taken care of by the `lock_guard` object):

```
void Future::setData(void* data[]){
    if(isDataReady)
        return;
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mut);
        this->data = data;
        isDataReady = true;
    }
    mut.unlock();       // <=== remove this
    cond.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to remove it. Thought, it still gives a error, around iteration #64... =/

Comment: If I only create around 50 Futures, i.e. do 50 iterations, there's no problem...Not deleting the mutex and condition in the Future's destructor poses a problem?

Comment: Is the problem the fact that I am using MinGW? I have specified the -mthreads flag, but even so it does not work... =/